# building Qt 5.2.0 with mingw 4.8.1

Tags: c++, mingw, qt5, installation

this is the first time i am trying to build Qt from source. so i need help from a expert. previously i used qt by installing it using their offline installers. but open cv library cannot be used with it. so i need to build qu frim source. im using win 7 64 bit OS.

i installed active perl, active python, ruby and git. the niwest versions and and added them to path. my path variable llist looks like follows.

[image]

then my mingw gcc version looks like follows.

[image]

then i build and installed ICU librarys as discribed in http://qt-project.org/wiki/Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW

then opened a cmd as adminisrtator and cd into qt extracted folder and configured as

```
  configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -opensource -nomake tests -opengl desktop
```

after configure complets then mingw32-make

it tooks about 1 hour in my i5 2.6ghz processor and ended with following errors.

[image]

what may be dhe mistake. am i doing enything wrong. has enybody successfully compiled Qt 5.2 with mingw 4.8.1 on a win 7 64bit system. if qt build successfully will it end with a messsage that `qt was build successfully` or somthing similar.

i know qt creator can be installed seperatly. but qt designer, will it also be built with qt librarys. can some expert help me with this issue. im trying this for several days.

eny helpwill be highly appricated... thank you....

Comment: their are 120 vives of this question. but no even a single comment or reply. some one who built qt librarys successfully help me. atleast tell me how long will a successful build take? when it finish build successfully will it end up will a msg "build completed successfully" or something similar for the user to know that the librarys are built correctly....???

Comment: Take a look at my **[other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425482/windows-c-compiler-with-full-c11-support-should-work-with-qt/19425966#19425966)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run make again. It was the same for me.
After two tries it compiled successfully.
I don't remember if it was the same error, but it always fail first time for me and then after running make again it compiles.
Previous versions didn't have this problem.
I have now problem compiling my code, because gcc crashes, but that's different problem.