# wild errors after loading cURL libraries into Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I am using cURL for MinGW64 from  http://curl.haxx.se/download.html v7.34.0 with the cURL wrappers from https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp and Qt 5.2.1
as soon as I load the libraries in .pro, wild syntax related error blossom by the truckloads  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9KQ.png  I really suspect it is version related, but I do not know the solution.

section of code it borks on example:

```
template<class T> class CurlError : public exception {
public:
    CurlError(const string error, const T code) : error(error), code(code) {}
    ~CurlError() throw() {};
    pair<string,T> what() noexcept;
private:
    string error;
    T code;
};
```

error output:

```
C:\Users\Brad2\Documents\GitHub\curlcpp\include\CurlError.h:25: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     pair<string,T> what() noexcept;
                         ^
```

Comment: Enabled C++11  `-std=c++11`

Comment: @Brandon How do I enable c++11 support in Qt5?

Comment: Is that a MinGW64 thing? Do I recompile MinGW with c++11 support?

Comment: I found this  ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425482/windows-c-compiler-with-full-c11-support-should-work-with-qt  How do I check to see if my build is using std::thread  ??

Comment: I did try to use qmake from the msvc libraries that are included with the default installation of Qt5 to see if they had c++11 but received an unrelated error  http://i.imgur.com/yTEJzU1.png

Comment: Just in case there is still confusion, the qmake equivalent of the `-std=c++11` cli option is by adding the two lines to your .pro file: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS = -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get this fixed. I went with QNetworkAccessManager instead of curl

Answer (score 1):

The following is from my `.pro` file in qt. You'll need to substitute directories as needed (`$$PWD` is the qmake variable for the root directory of your project, and I have curlcpp as a git-submodule in a folder called thirdparty)

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
QMAKE_LFLAGS = -std=c++11

INCLUDEPATH     += "$$PWD/thirdparty/curlcpp/include/"
LIBS            += -L"$$PWD/thirdparty/curlcpp/build/src/" \
                    -lcurlcpp \
                    -lcurl
```