# Issues installing pynini

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pynini

I'm having issues installing Pynini for python.
I tried doing it with using pip. From the command line it seems to work, but once I start testing functions, there is nothing, basically.
I tried downloading the tar.gz in http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/GRM/PyniniDownload
and from then, pip it, but it fails to build the 'wheel'.
It doesn't really tell me much more than this. I looked into the prereqs, but I'm now wondering if it is somehow related to python version.
I'm using **python 3**...
Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: cmd error]

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: windows 10. It might be related to my visual studio. going to append an image

Comment: visual studio 14 may not be 100% c++ 11 conforming http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/GRM/PyniniDownload/README.rst  Pynini is actually regularly tested with Python 2.7 and Ubuntu ... you might have better chances with those

Comment: You could edit the setup.py file and remove the -Wno-unused-function attribute, it seems that the visual studio compiler does not support this flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a standard-complying C++ 11 compiler is in system requirements (see openfst.org/twiki/pub/GRM/PyniniDownload/README.rst ).  try mingW64

[https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#GCC_-*MinGW*.28x86.29](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#GCC_-_MinGW_.28x86.29)

[Windows C++ compiler with full C++11 support (should work with Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425482/windows-c-compiler-with-full-c11-support-should-work-with-qt)